# Solve the following equation:

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

\begin{align*}
7yz+3zx&=4xy,\\ 
21yz-3zx&=4xy,\\ 
x+2y+3z&=19. 
\end{align*}

Answer: $(x,y,z)=(7,3,2)$

I'm not able to solve this. Steps?

Comment: I was getting (7,7,2). Now I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Adding the first two equations we have
$$28yz=8xy\qquad\iff\qquad y(7z-2x)=0$$

Now, try two cases:

1) when $y=0$,

2) when $7z-2x=0$,

Comment: I got it. Thanks :)